# Consider gene is countable, can anyone give a concrete example of "a gene"?

Tags: genetics, genomics, gene, genomes

[gene](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/gene) is a countable noun but people always say genes, so what is A gene?

for instance, Each chromosome contains many genes, so, which part of the chromosome of Escherichia coli could be `A gene`?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It is expected that you will demonstrate that you have done research on your own before asking questions here — for example you could start with this: https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/primer/basics/gene ——— Please also take the time to check out the tour: biology.stackexchange.com/tour and then the help pages on how to ask questions on this site: biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are about 20,000 genes in the human genome. Here are the first 5 genes (following alphabetical order) on chromosome 1:

- AADACL3: Arylacetamide deacetylase-like 3
- AADACL4: Arylacetamide deacetylase-like 4
- ACADM: acyl-Coenzyme A dehydrogenase, C-4 to C-12 straight chain
- ACTL8: Actin-like 8
- ADGRL2 (1p31.1): adhesion G protein-coupled receptor L2